# Какой параметр нужно передать в метод?

Tags: c#

Я хочу вывести в консоль список всех предметов класса `Merchant` , но не пойму, что мне передавать в метод `merchant.ShowItemList();`, какой параметр? Насколько я понимаю, из-за того, что у меня коллекция `protected`, то я не могу передать в качестве параметра коллекцию класса `Merchant`, но я хочу чтобы соблюдалась инкапсуляция

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Character character = new Character();
        Merchant merchant = new Merchant();

        Console.WriteLine("Список товаров продавца:");
        merchant.ShowItemList();     
    }

    class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public int Price { get; private set; }

        public Item(string name, int price)
        {
            Name = name;
            Price = price;
        }
    }

    class Character
    {
        protected List<Item> Items;

        public void ShowItemList(List<Item> items)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}: {items[i].Name} - {items[i].Price}");
            }
        }
    }

    class Merchant : Character
    {
        public Merchant()
        {
            Items = new List<Item>()
            {
            new Item ("Меч", 150),
            new Item ("Щит", 300),
            new Item ("Посох", 500),
            };
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перепишите Ваш метод, который будет обращаться к защищённой переменной собственного класса:

```
public void ShowItemList()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}: {Items[i].Name} - {Items[i].Price}");
            }
        }
```

и вызывайте ничего не передавая

Comment: блин точно, а я ломал голову, спасибо